# Installing Python Module to non-root directory

Tags: python, module, installation

First time posting on this site.

I'm trying to install a python module named Pygments into my local directory at work (non-root).  I am using C Shell, so i changed default path using

```
setenv PYTHONPATH "~/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages:${PYTHONPATH}"
```

(with usr/lib/... being self-made empty directories made to mimic the system's hierarchy at my boss's suggestion).  I attempted to run

```
python setup.py install
```

however, I got the following error.

```
/usr/lib64/python2.4/distutils/dist.py:236: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'zip_safe'
warnings.warn(msg)
/usr/lib64/python2.4/distutils/dist.py:236: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'include_package_data'
warnings.warn(msg)
running install
running build
running build_py
running build_scripts
running install_lib
creating /usr/local/lib64
error: could not create '/usr/local/lib64': Read-only file system
```

I want the module to install to my local directory and not to any root directory.  I've been stuck on this for a couple of days.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Colten

Extra Information:  I have setup.py in ~/Pygments-1.6, and I only have write access to directories within ~/.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why you are trying to do this. But just in case, have you looked into using virtualenv to have local copies of these modules. You can find and install howto here: https://python-guide.readthedocs.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs.html

Comment: Did you check what happens when changing the `PYTHONHOME` environment variable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PYTHONPATH is where python looks for modules, not where it chooses to **install** modules.  You need to specify that on the `setup.py` line:

```
python setup.py install --prefix=${HOME}/usr/
```

or something similar.  Another thing that you'll see in these cases is:

```
python setup.py install --user
```

which will put it in:  `'${HOME}/.local/lib/pythonX.Y/site-packages'` (And I believe that this path should be searched by python for modules by default.)